# flatMap and `Ambiguous reference to member` error

Tags: swift3, init, flatmap

Consider the following code:

```
typealias PersonRecord = [String : AnyObject]

struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    public init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

extension Person {
    init?(record : PersonRecord) {
        guard let name = record["name"] as? String,
        let age = record["age"] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Now I want to create an array of `Person`s from an array of `Record`s:

```
let records = // load file from bundle
let persons = records.flatMap(Person.init)
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: ambiguous reference to member 'init(name:age:)'
```

If I move the `failable initializer` out of the extension, I still get the same error.

What am I missing here, is this not a correct usage of `flatMap`?

**EDIT** - solved:

Found the error: the code that read in the records file from disk, returned the wrong type. Once I fixed that, the error went away.

Comment: Compiles fine for me, assuming `records` is of type `[PersonRecord]`. As with all weird compiler errors, try cleaning your build folder – and if you're in  a playground, try it in a full project.

Comment: That's good to know; I moved that code to a brand new PlayGround, and no errors. How do I clean the build folder for a playground, if any?

Comment: I don't believe you can (at least not easily) in a playground. Personally, I would avoid using playgrounds to begin with, as they're notoriously buggy – a full project is a much better Swift environment.

Comment: Hmm, I moved the whole playground code (of which the above was just a short snippet) to a full project, and am still getting the error. So something else is going on. `Person` actually confirms to a protocol (`Nameable`, which only has one property: `name`), could that interfere?

Comment: Not from what I can tell – although in any case it would be really helpful if you could reduce your code down to a [mcve], and update the question with that example.

Comment: Fixed - see my updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work

```
let persons = records.flatMap(Person.init)
```

the param passed to the `flatMap` closure must be the same type received by  `Person.init`, so it must be `PersonRecord`.

Then records must be a list of `PersonRecord`, something like this

```
let records: [PersonRecord] = []
```

Now it works

```
let persons = records.flatMap(Person.init)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times the `Ambiguous reference to member` in a `map` or `flatMap` is because the return type isn't specified

```
array.flatMap({ (item) -> ObjectToReturn? in })
```