# Keeping an index with flatMap in Swift

Tags: swift3, flatmap

This is a follow-up to this question:

[flatMap and `Ambiguous reference to member` error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196077/flatmap-and-ambiguous-reference-to-member-error)

There I am using the following code to convert an array of `Record`s to an array of `Person`s:

```
let records = // load file from bundle
let persons = records.flatMap(Person.init)
```

Since this conversion can take some time for big files, I would like to monitor an index to feed into a progress indicator.

Is this possible with this `flatMap` construction? One possibility I thought of would be to send a notification in the init function, but I am thinking counting the records is also possible from within `flatMap` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yup! Use [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1687832-enumerated).

```
let records = // load file from bundle
let persons = records.enumerated().flatMap { offset, record in
    print(offset)
    return Person(record)
}
```

Just note that what you get is an `offset` (always counting up from `0`). As the documentation clarifies:

> When you enumerate a collection, the integer part of each pair is a counter for the enumeration, but is not necessarily the index of the paired value. These counters can be used as indices only in instances of zero-based, integer-indexed collections, such as `Array` and `ContiguousArray`. For other collections the counters may be out of range or of the wrong type to use as an index. To iterate over the elements of a collection with its indices, use the `zip(_:_:)` function.

If you want values that you can reliably use indices, use `zip`, as they suggest:

```
let a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
let slice = a.dropFirst(3) // Indices start at 3

for (index, element) in zip(slice.indices, slice) {
  print(slice[index], element) // The index is always valid for subscripting back into the collection
}
```

Comment: Amazing, how simple and elegant!

Comment: Welcome to Swift! :p

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you, @Alexander!